# Attach to Tangle Transaction

Tags: tangle, attach-to-tangle, signing

The "attach to tangle"-transaction is a special zero value transaction to attach a newly generated address to tangle.

The "attach to tangle"-transactions contains signatures such as following transactions:

- https://thetangle.org/transaction/TNPSPHMZAPYVGG9KBMUSACJONDIKUQNJUQSZPBUJEHJODWXRTO9XSAJPSHZUYADXXCLXCPRVBKLCA9999
- https://thetangle.org/transaction/9GNKOHOBLUUTN9SFTZSELLAIAMLXX9EFUN9FICROZ9KT9YXY9WYBDSVDYSXZXJEKRZHTIUTIINRBZ9999,

My question is, which address is signed when "attach to tangle" is performed since no IOTAs are transferred?

Does the "attach to tangle"-transaction contain a signature corresponding to newly generated address?

Answer (score 3):

The transaction that is done when *"attaching to tangle"* doesn't have a sender address. It's just one address—the new address—in that transaction. The action just adds an address connected to your seed to the tangle. It doesn't reveal any part of your key either. If you look at your linked transaction the signature field is actually empty (only 9s) as well as containing a message. If it was a spending transaction there would be a signature. (Cf. [Transactions and Bundles](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/transactions-and-bundles.html)).

Comment: not all non-zero transactions need a signature, only those that spend from an address (amount negative).

Comment: how can we differentiate whether the signature field contains signature or message?

Comment: @mihi do you mean non-zero transactions does not necessarily spend, only non-zero transactions that spend needs signature? I did not get this point in which scenario non-zero transaction does not spend?

Comment: when a bundle moves money around, (at least) one of its transaction spends the money (and needs signature) and (at least) one of its transaction receives it (and does not need a signature, so you can put some message for the recipient here).

Comment: @mihi is *non-zero spending transaction* accurate?

Comment: yep. Although the non-zero is kind of redundant :-)

Comment: uh, yeah, of course